# How do Fluorescent molecules emit light in a different wavelength than the one needed to excite them?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, wavelength, fluorescence

if it took a very certain amount of energy to excite an atom, how come when it de-excites it emits a photon of lower energy?
I know that's what scintillators do, I Just want to know the microscopic process behind it.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained quite well in the corresponding Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence#/media/File:Jablonski_Diagram_of_Fluorescence_Only.png The atom emmits the energy in several smaller portions falling back to the ground state passing short-lived intermediate states which have energy values between the excited and the ground state (see linked graphics).